# Using assimp makes compilations 30 times slower

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm using cmake and including assimp with the following two lines:

```
add_subdirectory(external/assimp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)
```

I've also added `#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>` into a my cpp.

Usually the compilation takes ~2 seconds.
However, if I actually use assimp in my code, such as adding the following line:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;
```

with no mention of assimp anywhere else, it jumps to ~55 seconds. Note that `#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>` is the present in both cases.
Step `[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/src/Project.cpp.obj` takes the majority of time.

If I update the code, as long as assimp is used, recompilation will take another ~55 seconds to recompile.

I've tried putting the include into the precompiled header, but the behaviour is the same.
What am I doing wrong? Why does it take so long?

I'm using CLion, but with gcc from msys2/mingw64 installation.

Here's the full cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(PathTracer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp src/Project.h src/Project.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Headers)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(external/glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)

add_subdirectory(external/assimp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)

add_subdirectory(shaders)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} Shaders)

target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE src/pch.h)

if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets)
    #Developer mode needs to be active on Windows 10 or later for this command to work
    file(CREATE_LINK ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets SYMBOLIC)
endif ()

if (ENABLE_VALIDATION)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_VALIDATION=1)
endif (ENABLE_VALIDATION)

if (ENABLE_API_DUMP)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_API_DUMP=1)
endif (ENABLE_API_DUMP)
```

Comment: Do you want to use an already built assimp library installed in your system or sitting somewhere or do you want to build the assimp library yourself? `add_subdirectory(external/assimp)` is doing the latter.

Comment: I want to build it myself, but I don't want to rebuild it every time I recompile my own code.

Comment: You may look into precompiled headers. Not sure if MinGW support them, though.

Comment: Oh, I've tried. It made no difference. Even with the header in the precompiled header, compilation time drastically changes depending on whether I actually use Assimp or not.
Could it be the linker?

Comment: As mentioned by kevin, you're building assimp yourself.
If you use `find_package(assimp CONFIG REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)` and remove the line with `add_subdirectory`, and use the precompiled header, then there is no more recompilation of the assimp, and the build skips them. I'm doing that in my own project.

Comment: @OctoPoulos Could you elaborate on how you're doing this? I'm facing the same issue of very slow linking time, but am using `find_package(assimp CONFIG REQUIRED` and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)`

Answer (score 0):

If it is linking that takes a ridiculously long time, link to Assimp as a dynamic/shared library rather than static.

As to how you would do that: `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)` before you `add_subdirectory(assimp)`.